# Transplant hard drive from Toshiba Tecra M7 to Toshiba Portege m780

Tags: hard-drive, toshiba-laptop

I want to transplant my hard drive from my Toshiba Tecra M7 tablet running Windows 7 (full license - not OEM) to my new Toshiba Portege m780. They are both tablet pc's with Intel processors - Tecra has Intel Core 2 Duo; Portege has Intel i5. 
I was planning to clone the drive on the Tecra and then install into the Portege. I want to keep the system intact.
I expect there to be problems. I want to minimize/eliminate as many as possible.
Please, I am not looking for "Just do a fresh install" as an answer. If it's not going to work, that's fine, but doing a fresh install is a non-starter for me.

Comment: Just as a follow up for anyone attempting the same, the transplant didn't work. I had cloned the drive and then installed the clone. It shut down during start-up. My work around was to use a program from Laplink called PCMover Professional. It transferred programs, files and settings from one computer to the other. Cost was $20 off eBay. Took roughly 1/2 a day once it was set up. Pleased with the result.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem. I've added it to the answer space, if you feel you would like to add it yourself, do so and I'll remove the community wiki one :)

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's comment:

Just as a follow up for anyone attempting the same: the transplant didn't work. I had cloned the drive and then installed the clone. It shut down during start-up.

My work around was to use a program from Laplink called PCMover Professional. It transferred programs, files and settings from one computer to the other. Cost was $20 off eBay. It took roughly 1/2 a day once it was set up. Pleased with the result.